# using a conditional statement modifier in Rails Templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails template (.rhtml file) generating a Javascript object. It looks something like the following:

```
var volumes = {
  <% for volume in @volumes %>
    <%= volume.id %> : <%= volume.data %> 
    <%= ',' unless volume === @volumes.last %>
  <% end %>
};
```

Note the `unless` statement modifier to suppress printing the comma after the last element (to satisfy Internet Explorer, which incredibly doesn't support trailing commas in JSON properties declarations).

This appears to work, but as a matter of style, do people think it is reasonable to rely on `<%= value unless condition %>` in the template generating an appropriate `render` call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why not, but generally if you find yourself conditionalizing a comma on the last member, you probably want to use `join` instead:

```
<%= @volumes.map {|v| "#{v.id} : #{v.data}"}.join "," %>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to contruct JSON (and BTW you are constructing JavaScript Object not Array) then I suggest to use to_json method:

```
var volumes = <%= @volumes.inject({}){|h,v| h.merge(v.id=>v.data)}.to_json %>;
```

or

```
var volumes = <%= Hash[*@volumes.map{|v| [v.id, v.data]}.flatten].to_json %>;
```

Even better would be to move Ruby Hash construction to model as it is too complex for view.

```
class Volume
  def self.to_hash(volumes)
    Hash[*volumes.map{|v| [v.id, v.data]}.flatten]
  end
end
```

and then in view you can put much simpler code:

```
var volumes = <%= Volume.to_hash(@volumes).to_json %>;
```

Comment: Thanks, and you're right, it's JSON object, not Array. Fixed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Or even:

```
<%= @volumes.map { |v| "#{v.id} : #{v.data}"}.to_sentence -%>
```

To get "a: something, b: something else, c: anything, and d: another thing."

Comment: Not exactly legal in JavaScript, but hey, whatever turns you on.

Comment: Damn you Jim.  You come over to my house and eat my homemade ribs, then you point out in public that I didn't even read the question and notice the "var volumes = ..."  What's next, stealing my puppy?

Comment: Mmm, homemade ribs. Thanks, dude, they were delicious.